# Mapstruct - Multiple parameters to inner class

Tags: mapstruct

I'm trying to map to a inner class but it's not working.

I have the following Pojos:

```
public record Author(UUID id, String name) {}

public record Book(Author author) {}
```

And this is the mapper:

```
@Mapper
public interface BookMapper {
    @Mapping(target="author", source=".");
    Book map(UUID id, String name);

    Author map(UUID id, String name);
}
```

But I get this error when compiling:

`BookMapperImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method map(UUID,String)`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the "not abstract" error the only one you are getting? I would imagine that there are some other errors as using `source = "."` doesn't really work for multi source mapping methods

Comment: I just get that error. Any workarounds that you may know?

Comment: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2941

Answer (score 0):

> BookMapperImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method map(UUID,String)

That is a strange error, it means that MapStruct generated some partial implementation due to something else, but it didn't report an addition error. This is most likely a bug in MapStruct.

Nevertheless, using `source = "."` doesn't work with multiple source parameters and even without that it won't be able to pass the mapping to the `Author` mapping.

I would suggest using a custom method for mapping this e.g.

```java
@Mapper
public interface BookMapper {
    @Mapping(target="author", source=".");
    default Book map(UUID id, String name) {
        Author author = map(id, name);
        return author != null ? new Book(author) : null;
    }

    Author map(UUID id, String name);
}
```